# How do you repair a deeply scratched flute?

Tags: flute, repair

I tried removing the tarnish off my flute by using a plastic scrubber, and then I realized that I scratched my flute. How do you repair a deeply scratched flute without taking it in for maintenance?

Comment: I'd put my money on "you don't"; but consider adding a picture of the scratch to your post. That might offer some helpful detail to someone who understands flute repair.

Comment: I would put my money on the same bet than @Aaron, but a photo would help give a better answer. Depending on the original finish of the flute, and the scratch, you might be able to polish it back…

Comment: What model flute?    Base metal vs. silver-plated vs.  solid silver   matters